# how can I read only odd columns from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[select all even columns of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868700/python-pandas-how-can-i-simultaneously-select-all-even-columns-of-a-big-datafr/60510111?noredirect=1#comment107047441_60510111)

Can someone tell me how I would do for odd columns please?

Comment: `df.loc[:, 1::2]`

Comment: Thank you, it worked

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci You should add that as an answer (along with a little explanation about why it works) so that people can vote on it and the OP can accept it.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica alright let's go

Answer (score 2):

## How does a slice work?

When you're doing:

```
df.loc[:, a:b:c]
```

You are saying:

- `:` do not touch the rows
- `,` the separator between what to do on the rows (left) and on the columns (right)
- `[a:b:c]` extract a slice that begins at index `a`, finishes at index `b` (excluded) and with a padding of `c`

In your case, you chose `c=2` to skip every other column (0, 2, 4...) and `a=1` to shift your slice from one column (1, 2, 3...).